# How to return a temporary collection in the callback of a mongodb find() using node-mongodb-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to return a temporary collection from a find() operation instead of a cursor? I am using the node-mongodb-native driver and I want to run a mapReduce on the results of the find() operation. Something like this:

```
client.open(function(err) {
    client.collection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {
        collection.find( {days_since_epoch: {$gte: query.begin}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            // Need to run a mapReduce here on the results
            // Preferably on a temporary collection instead of the default cursor or array above
       });
    });
});
```

There is probably a better way to do this so I would be up for that also. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nope but the map-reduce function takes a query so you don't need the find :)

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#mapreduce

Comment: Thanks. Something that was unclear to me was whether that query was being applied towards the map or reduce function. I guess it has to be the map function because the original keys would not be present when the output is passed to the reduce function. Right?

Comment: yeah it's just basically a filter, comes in very handy if you are doing incremental map-reduces where you might be choosing a time series based on dates or an incremental counter and storing the position for each time you run map-reduce.

Comment: it's also worth looking at the aggregation framework coming in 2.2 as it might be able to most of the group/orders map-reduce is used for http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework